# EXCEL - Ranking with multiply conditions and tie breakers

Tags: excel, ranking, rank

I am trying to make a conditional ranking in this chart to create a tie breaker:

[Dropbox link to excel xlsx file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zkata0vrkgfz2fx/Brackets.xlsx?dl=0)!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdVcX.png)

On the right you can see the total score and ranking from the Match 1,2,3 (sum) on line A and C I have a tie score (3 points and both ranked at 2nd place), I'd like to to add a 2nd and 3rd conditions to determinate the final ranking. If there is a tie in score (both are in same ranking), then to determine who is 2nd and who is 3rd place I want to use the values from the XX's column first. The higher value will win the 2nd place and in a case there is still a tie (as both are the same value of 0), it will continue and check the value on the X's column and since line `C = 27` and line `A = 21`, line C will be ranked as 2nd place and line A will be ranked as 3rd place. Also will like to add an option to continue with 3 condition if there is still a tie.

I am using a simple ranks formula `=RANK(AK7,$AK$7:$AK$10)` to determine the rank.

Comment: thanks Jordan for the edit, any chance you can answer it?